# This is returning error. (django 1.5)

Tags: django

**

> This is the ValueError it is returning. The view
>   poster.views.post_tweet didn't return an HttpResponse object

**
     poster/views.py

```
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

 def post_tweet(request, tweet_id=None):
     tweet = None
     if tweet_id:
        tweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, id=tweet_id)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = TweetForm(request.POST, instance=tweet)
         if form.is_valid():
             new_tweet = form.save(commit=False)
             new_tweet.state = 'pending'
             new_tweet.save()
             send_review_email(tweet)
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/thankyou/')
     else:
         form = TweetForm(instance=tweet)
         return render(request,'post_tweet.html',{'form': form})

 def thank_you(request):
     tweets_in_queue = Tweet.objects.filter(
        state='pending').aggregate(Count('id')).values()[0]
     return render(request, 'thank_you.html',
         {'tweets_in_queue': tweets_in_queue})
```

> myproject/urls.py

```
 url(r'^post/', include('poster.urls'))
```

> poster/urls.py

```
 url(r'^thankyou', 'thank_you'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a POST, but the form isn't valid, you're not returning anything.  If you move the `return render(request,'post_tweet.html',{'form': form})` left by one indentation level it should all work.